# setInterval: why pass a function that returns a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While studying React, I came across following code block [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged):

```
this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
);
```

Here, the first argument to setInterval is a function that returns tick() function. If I replace the 1st argument to setInterval with just `this.tick`, it does not work (meaning, clock stops ticking). Whereas it works with just passing the function [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html).
Why is it so?

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) takes in a function. Why do we have to pass in an arrow-function that returns a function instead?

Comment: More like calling context of `this`....   So did you write it as `setInterval(
      () => this.tick, 1000)` or `setInterval(this.tick, 1000)`

Comment: You are *calling* a function with `this.tick()`. You will only return a function if `tick()` returns a function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an arrow function you ensure that the `this` value remains the same even if the function is executed in another context (like setInterval)

It is effectively the same as

```
this.timerID = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
```

Comment: Got it. So, if `binding` had not been required in React, or tick() had no use of `this` (to access the instance of this class), we might have as well used the function name directly. I checked by calling an external function directly from setInterval and it works. This helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `()=>this.tick()` is short hand for:

```
()=>{
  return this.tick()
}
```

When your lambda only has 1 line of code, you can leave out the brackets `{...}`

You're effectively returning the returned value of executing `this.tick()`

Comment: The other important thing to mention is that the `=>` syntax also preserves `this`, while `this.tick` alone would not.